# Can't query node from open62541 server to milo client

Tags: opc-ua, milo, node-opcua, open62541

I have an OPC-UA server implemented with open62541.

I have an OPC-UA client implemented with milo.

My open62541 server works when I request its nodes it with an open62541 client.

My milo client is able to request nodes from an milo server.

My milo client is able to connect to my open62541 server, and retrive information, such as the PRODUCT_NAME. But it is unable to get any node I created on my server.

Do you know if it is a known issue ? Do you know if they is any special configuration to make ? Do anyone has an example of code working ?

Comment: It is always a good idea to check if some well-established program works with given program. I recommend UA-Expert as client program.

Answer (score 0):

No known issues, you'll have to provide code examples or logs or more information.